# Single word request for "basic and plain"

Tags: word-request, single-word

I seem to believe that there must be a single word that means something to the extent of:

> Basic and plain design/look.

In a sentence:

> I believe the design for this graphic user interface is too *missing word*.

Looks like "basic" can be used here, but I seem to think their is another word.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/simple  https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/plain https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/spartan https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/uncomplicated https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sparse

Comment: As far as design is concerned, it sounds like you might be looking for the word **minimalist**.

Comment: Either "basic" or " plain" on their own would do.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes! The word I am looking for is "mininalistic"!

Comment: @BillyKerr You could perhaps post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of simple? You could say that the interface is too simple, which would mean that it is both basic and plain.